# COM using CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream to marshal interface

Tags: c++, com

I have a method that register functions and interface in C++, and I am using `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream` to marshal an interface pointer to a method in another thread.

In `RegisterFunction`:

```
HRESULT hr = CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream(IID_Function, function, &stream);
```

Releasing it in `GetFunction`:

```
HRESULT hr = CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream(stream, IID_Function, reinterpret_cast<void**>(&function));
```

Since I will be calling `GetFunction` more than once and `CoGetInterfaceAndReleaseStream` only releases a stream once, how do I save the stream to use it again?

---

I tried using `IGlobalInterfaceTable`, but I can't get it to work.

I registered the Inteface successfully in `RegisterFunction`:

```
DWORD dwCookie = 0;
int a = 0;
if (pGIT == NULL) {
  HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable,
     NULL,
     CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
     IID_IGlobalInterfaceTable,
     (void **)&pGIT);
  if (hr != S_OK) {
     throw _com_error(hr);
  }
}

if (dwCookie == 0) {
  HRESULT hr = pGIT->RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(function, IID_Function, &dwCookie);
  if (hr != S_OK) {
     throw _com_error(hr);
  }
}
```

But when I tried to retrieve it in `GetFunction`:

```
   IGlobalInterfaceTable* GIT = NULL;
      if (GIT == NULL) {
         hr = CoCreateInstance(CLSID_StdGlobalInterfaceTable,
            NULL,
            CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
            IID_IGlobalInterfaceTable,
            (void **)&GIT);
         if (FAILED(hr)) {
            exit(0);
         }
      }

      hr = pGIT->GetInterfaceFromGlobal(dwCookie, IID_Function, (void**)&function);
      if (FAILED(hr)) {
            exit(0);
      }
```

I get an HR error of invalidArg when I tried to RegisterInterfaceInGlobal (even though it uses the same parameter as CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream except for the cookie)

Comment: You can't do it with CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream (it is a convenience method for interface pointers that will be extracted exactly once), instead use CoMarshalInterface/CoUnmarshalInterface with a stream created using ShCreateMemStream

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As SoronelHaetir stated, you can't do this with `CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream`. It can only (un)marshal an interface one time.

Look at using [`IGlobalInterfaceTable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms678517.aspx) instead. You  can register your COM object in the table one time, and then retrieve the object from the table in any thread/apartment as many times as you want, until you revoke the object from the table.

Comment: I looked into using IGlobalInterfaceTable and I can't seem to get it to work

Comment: @user3910703 that is because you are not using it correctly. I updated my answer.

Comment: I think I am getting an error in RegisterInterfaceInGlobal(function, IID_IJavaScriptFunction, &dwCookie) too where I was getting an invalid arg hr error. If it works for CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream, shouldn't those parameter works for RegisterInterrfaceInGlobal too?

Comment: @user3910703 yes, it takes the same parameters, just with a cookie instead of a stream. I use `IGlobalInterfaceTable` in my own projects that pass COM objects between threads and apartments, so I know it works.

Comment: I think it should work too, but RegisterInterfaceInGlobal is giving me an E_INVALIDARG error. For RegisterInterfaceInGlobal, I used (function, IID_function, &dwCookie) with it being set as DWORD dwCookie = 0.  This is similar to what I used as CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream, which is (IID_function, function, &stream). I checked the parameter and function is a of null value but of type CComQIPtr of the IID_function and IID_function is of type _GUID.

Comment: @user3910703: I don't know what to tell you then. Unless `function` is a null pointer, or you have a bad declaration of `RegisterInterfaceInGlobal()` (like missing the `stdcall` calling convention), then it should be working. It works fine for me, and I've been using it for years.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do it with  CoMarshalInterThreadInterfaceInStream, it is a convenience method for interface pointers that will be extracted just once.

Instead use CoMarshalInterface/CoUnmarshalInterface and use a stream created with ShCreateMemStream.